# A good pattern or example for a rolling data window in C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, rest

We're developing a system that includes a search function which could return several hundred (possibly a couple thousand) complex objects as a query result.  The UI is web-based, and I'm reticent to shove hundreds of objects over the wire, even in summary form, since the useful amount of data to display to the user per object is fairly large.  I'd like to avoid traditional paging (30 items per page, some number of pages listed at the bottom), and would rather see something that simulates all the results being displayed on one page, but have the data load as the user scrolls down.  To keep large data sets from swamping the browser, I'm thinking I'd like to see data disappear "off the top" as they scroll down, loading again if they scroll up.

I tried *GIFY* first, honest I did.  The problem is I'm not a web developer and I don't know what to call this thing, though I know it's not a new concept.  I tried "**rolling data window**", "**scrolling data window**", "**web ui data window**", and a couple other things before giving up entirely and coming here, hat in hand.

Can anyone identify for me a pattern or example of this thing I'm describing?  I presume it has to be done in the controller, with the UI simply asking for the next chunk of data in whatever direction in the stack it happens to be scrolling.

Comment: infinite scrolling is the term.

Comment: Evidently I've asked a question improperly.  How could I have done better?

Comment: requesting off-site resources are off topic.

Comment: Should I delete the question, or leave it as a warning to others?

Comment: Not any more, evidently; it's got an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try "Lazy Loading" concept where the loading will happen dynamically as per the requirement.

[you can read the concept here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/652556/Can-you-explain-Lazy-Loading)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.